# To pass input data as array to jquery

Tags: jquery, sql, ajax, codeigniter, formwizard

i have the requirement where student answer questions (which questions  retrive from database) using foreach,and  i have to pass to jquery when all answer filled and then to controller and save to database.

```
<div>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($questions as $question) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td ><?php echo $question['id']; ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $question['question']; ?> </td>
            <td><input type='text' name='name' required="required" class="form-control" placeholder='Enter Your Answer'></td>
            // this is answer field associated with each question
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>  
    </tbody> 
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" id ="next" type="button" >Next</button>
```

and when student fills all answer this (question ans answer) pass to jquery
and this is script

```
<script>
          $(document).ready(function($){
            $(".gg").click(function(){
            var array = $("input[name]").val();
            $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          datatype:"json",
          url: BASE_URL+"student/info",
          data: 'data='+array,

          success: function(response) {


          }});

        return false;
    });  
});
        </script>
```

when student submit answer, only first answer is pass to jquery function ,not able to pass all answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data is not proper fomat

```
data: {'data=': array_variable },
```

If you want to send all form data better you could serialize it and send it to your php side and serialize there.Like:

```
data : $('#form').serialize()
```

### ELSE Without Serialize

```
var textboxes = $('input[name="answer[]"]').val();
data : {'data':textboxes},
```

Comment: when i m doing console.log for $("input[name]").val(); that time i get only 1st answer

Comment: wrap it in a form and serialise the form you'll get all elements. Also Change name="name" to name="answer[]"

Comment: just serialise the form and send the serialised data. You could get all the form elements as serialized array

Comment: yes i tried .serialize() also but still i m getting only one post data

Comment: `var textboxes = $('input[name="answer[]"]').val();`
`data : {'data':textboxes},`

Answer (score 0):

You need to give dynamically name of input textbox

**In the Code**

```
<div>
      <form name='question' id='question' >
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($questions as $question) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td ><?php echo $question['id']; ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo $question['question']; ?> </td>
                <td><input type='text' name='name[<?php echo $question["id"]; ?>]' required="required" class="form-control" placeholder='Enter Your Answer'></td>
                // this is answer field associated with each question
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>  
        </tbody> 
      </form>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" id ="next" type="button" >Next</button>
```

In the Script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function($){
$("#id").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: BASE_URL+"student/info",
        data: $('#question').serialize(),

        success: function(response) {


        }});

        return false;
      });  
});     
</script>
```

Comment: does i have to use jquery each function to push data as array?

Comment: yeah, you can also use jquery each function. but that way very easier to implement.

Comment: `[<?php echo $question["id"]; ?>]` how this pass to script because when i tried no able to pass this to controller

Comment: It's a Dynamically Input textbox or not..?

Comment: this input text box associated with each question and this question retrive from db

Comment: all textbox make in one form and you can directly submit form using ajax. which i given in code. can you check this. all textbox is submitted as a array, and array id is your question is so it can easily identify using textbox name by array id.